# How to Rename Document with a dot in it. HELP :*( SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow-variable, rename

I am moving a file from one document library to another using a 2013 workflow but it keeps dropping the dot " . " from the file name.

"File 45.01"  Move Document -> Rename Document -> "Published File 45", it drops everything after the dot. It should be, "Published File 45.01".

I believe SPD designer uses C# and you can't use dots in variable names correct?

Would I need to do something with subtracting some string characters from the field and then adding them back in?  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated because i've been killing myself over this for the past week and can't get it working :(.

Thank you.

-Mark

Answer (score 0):

you can append a "." dot at the end of the filename before renaming in the workflow. this scenario truncates text only after the last "." dot hence the workaround to append a "." at the end of file name would work.
 you can create an activity to do this.